# Confusion with client and server side development in electron, node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, electron, require

I've built an app using electron.
I have many `require`'s in my code to node modules.

I start my app through `npm start` and it's all working but how do I make it work client-side
(when i package it with electron-packager)?

When I start the packaged app, the javascripts don't work because I used `require('electron').remote` and the scripts stop there.

I don't really get how to make this work, I'm new to all this stuff. I also downloaded require.js but it didn't solve my problem because i don't know what to do with the electron package. Any help?

Comment: I'm not clear about your question. There isn't really a client/server when using Electron - but there is a main process and one or more renderer/browser processes, perhaps that's what you mean. I doubt requirejs will help here, that may be overcomplicating it. If you can edit your question to include more specific details about the problem and any errors shown, someone may be able to help.

Comment: Adding to @JustinEmery, there are essentially two Node processes: a main process (this manages your electron app as a Windows process, allowing you to interact with core Windows APIs such as trays and dialogs), and a renderer process, which is a fancy front-end where you can use back-end code.

Comment: try browse the [electron documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/electron/topics)